# Remove part of string after a specific character in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

Given a `time` column as follows:

```
             time
0   2019Y8m16d10h
1    2019Y9m3d10h
2  2019Y9m3d10h58s
3    2019Y9m3d10h
```

How can I remove substrings start by `d`, I have tried with `df['time'].str.split('d')[0]`, but it doesn't work.

My desired result will like this. Thank you.

```
        time
0    2019Y8m16d
1    2019Y9m3d
2    2019Y9m3d
3    2019Y9m3d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need `str[0]` for select lists and then add `d`:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.split('d').str[0].add('d')
```

Or:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.split('(d)').str[:2].str.join('')
```

---

```
print (df)
         time
0  2019Y8m16d
1   2019Y9m3d
2   2019Y9m3d
3   2019Y9m3d
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.extract('(.+d)')
print (df)
         time
0  2019Y8m16d
1   2019Y9m3d
2   2019Y9m3d
3   2019Y9m3d
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but `d` get missing as well and I want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

```
df['time'].str.extract(r'([^d]+d)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use apply functionality to solve the purpose as follows:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['time'].split('d')[0]+'d',axis=1)
```